# Cannot define getter method in eigenclass in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to define a new getter method for an object. Here's the code that I'm writing in `irb`:

```
> eigenclass = class << self; self; end
> eigenclass.class_eval { attr_reader :foo }
```

I suppose that this code should add `foo` method to self object. But next lines say different

```
puts foo  
=> nil
foo = 1
=> 1       #Why is there no exception?
puts foo  
=> 1
puts @foo 
=> nil
```

Why is that?

Comment: You don't need your custom `eigenclass`. There is `singleton_class` already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `var = val` assigns a local variable rathen than calling a `setter` method.

You need to prefix it with `self.` in order to call the setter (and the actual getter in case you have a local variable with the same name), which throws the error you expect:

```
2.0.0p195 :001 > eigenclass = class << self; self; end
 => #<Class:#<Object:0x007fc6f98e24d0>>
2.0.0p195 :002 > eigenclass.class_eval { attr_reader :foo }
 => nil
2.0.0p195 :003 > foo
 => nil
2.0.0p195 :004 > foo = 20
 => 20
2.0.0p195 :005 > foo
 => 20
2.0.0p195 :006 > self.foo
 => nil
2.0.0p195 :007 > self.foo = 20
NoMethodError: undefined method `foo=' for main:Object
    from (irb):7
```

Answer (score 3):

You made two mistakes:
a) If you want full accessor (getter and setter), you should use:

```
eigenclass.class_eval { attr_accessor :foo }
```

b) If you want to use setter method, you should use `self` keyword, otherwise Ruby will set a local variable:

```
self.foo = 1
# => 1
puts @foo
# => 1
```

Or, without defining setter, you can set instance variable directly:

```
eigenclass.class_eval { attr_accessor :foo }
@foo = 1
puts @foo
# => 1
```